# XAF web column grouping

Tags: xaf

if anyone has work with eXpressApp Framework (XAF)
I'm trying to group the listView by either one or two columns in the collection, Web module without luck, thanks in advance

```
Private Sub SCA_ViewBy_Execute(sender As Object, e As SingleChoiceActionExecuteEventArgs) Handles SCA_ViewBy.Execute
    If SCA_ViewBy.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        Dim listEditor As GridListEditor = TryCast((CType(View, ListView)).Editor, GridListEditor)
        If listEditor IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim gridView As GridView = listEditor.GridView

            gridView.BeginSort()
            Try
                gridView.ClearGrouping()
                gridView.Columns("Division").GroupIndex = 0
                gridView.Columns("SubDivision").GroupIndex = -1
            Finally
                gridView.EndSort()
            End Try
        End If

    ElseIf SCA_ViewBy.SelectedIndex = 1 Then

        Dim listEditor As GridListEditor = TryCast((CType(View, ListView)).Editor, GridListEditor)

        If listEditor IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim gridView As GridView = listEditor.GridView

            gridView.BeginSort()
            Try
                gridView.ClearGrouping()
                gridView.Columns("Division").GroupIndex = 0
                gridView.Columns("SubDivision").GroupIndex = 1
            Finally
                gridView.EndSort()
            End Try


        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I found a solution that works

```
Private Sub SCA_ViewBy_Execute(sender As Object, e As SingleChoiceActionExecuteEventArgs) Handles SCA_ViewBy.Execute
    If SCA_ViewBy.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        '    Dim listEditor As GridListEditor = TryCast((CType(View, ListView)).Editor, GridListEditor)
        '    If listEditor IsNot Nothing Then
        '        Dim gridView As GridView = listEditor.GridView

        '        gridView.BeginSort()
        '        Try
        '            gridView.ClearGrouping()
        '            gridView.Columns("Division").GroupIndex = 0
        '            gridView.Columns("SubDivision").GroupIndex = -1
        '        Finally
        '            gridView.EndSort()
        '        End Try
        '    End If

        Dim listEditor1 As ASPxGridListEditor = TryCast((CType(View, ListView)).Editor, ASPxGridListEditor)
        If listEditor1 IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim gridView As ASPxGridView = CType(listEditor1.Grid, ASPxGridView)
            gridView.ClientInstanceName = View.Id
            Dim divisionColumns As GridViewDataColumn = TryCast(gridView.Columns("Division"), GridViewDataColumn)
            'Dim subdivisionColumns As GridViewDataColumn = TryCast(gridView.Columns("SubDivision"), GridViewDataColumn)
            If divisionColumns IsNot Nothing Then
                'detailsColumns.DataItemTemplate = New UpDownButtonsTemplate()
                gridView.ClearSort()
                gridView.SortBy(divisionColumns, DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Ascending)
                gridView.GroupBy(divisionColumns, 0)
                gridView.ExpandAll()
            End If
        End If


    ElseIf SCA_ViewBy.SelectedIndex = 1 Then

        Dim listEditor1 As ASPxGridListEditor = TryCast((CType(View, ListView)).Editor, ASPxGridListEditor)
        If listEditor1 IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim gridView As ASPxGridView = CType(listEditor1.Grid, ASPxGridView)
            gridView.ClientInstanceName = View.Id
            Dim divisionColumns As GridViewDataColumn = TryCast(gridView.Columns("Division"), GridViewDataColumn)
            Dim subdivisionColumns As GridViewDataColumn = TryCast(gridView.Columns("SubDivision"), GridViewDataColumn)
            If divisionColumns IsNot Nothing Then
                'detailsColumns.DataItemTemplate = New UpDownButtonsTemplate()
                gridView.ClearSort()
                gridView.SortBy(divisionColumns, DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Ascending)
                gridView.GroupBy(divisionColumns, 0)
                gridView.GroupBy(subdivisionColumns, 1)
                gridView.ExpandAll()
            End If
        End If
    Else

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: the only difficulty is that I can't get the singleChoiceAction to display the selectedItem or Index when the application starts again